# VeraCrypt Hidden Volume

Tags: macos

I have been trying to create a second hidden volume in one outer volume and in my quest to find out if this is possible, I came across this site with an unknown version of VeraCrypt with this option or step:
[image]

I am using VeraCrypt version 1.25.9 on my MacOS Ventura 13.4.1, and there's NO such option on that version. Could you please tell me how I can obtain a version of VeraCrypt with that option or step?

Comment: It might have to do with which platform it is on. Seems here that on Linux it doesn't have it but on Windows it does https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/issues/401#issue-401147293

Comment: Why are you using 3rd party tools to do this? The Mac can easily create a virtual disk, dmg or sparse image, which you can hide by putting a dot in front of its name. It makes the whole question into one big [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Might it be file system dependent, available for NTFS (i.e., Windows), and not others, e.g., ext4 or APFS?  BTW, Veracrypt_1.25.9.dmg is the latest Mac version... do not download from dodgy alternate source.

Comment: @Tetsujin If I understand correctly, the OP is looking for the plausble deniability feature (at the expense of risk of data being overwritten).  It was a specific feature of Truecrypt [and I assume partially implemented in Veracrypt] which arguably should not be something built into a typical OS due to dataloss risk.

Comment: The step in that Windows screenshot is missing on my macOS VeraCrypt 1.25.9. But Normal Mode (i.e. create outer and inner volumes) is what VC does for me. Just no option to put the inner volume inside an existing volume.